# How to implement splash screen using react native functional components using hooks?

Tags: react-native

Please suggest me a solution if come across this problem.
I tried implementing

```
npm i react-native-splash-screen --save
```

then I used `useEffect()`
But I could not see any splash screen on app

```
useEffect(() => {  setTimeout(() => SplashScreen.hide() , 1000);  })
```

I am new to react and I'm not much familiar about things. If anyone knows any solution please suggest.

Comment: Be more specific, please.

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the integration of the package you installed to the letter, in its documentation it is clear how to integrate it into your application.

The useEffect that you show, try to use it without the TimeOut, and you must place it in the App.js.

Remember that most of the configuration happens in the Android folder of your project.